# Apache Camel: Splitter, CBR or Dynamic Router?

Tags: java, apache-camel, routes, splitter, integration-patterns

I have the following POJO:

```
public class MyPOJO {
    private Fizz fizz;
    private Buzz buzz;

    // ctor, getters, setters, etc.
}
```

And the following route (Spring XML):

```
<route id="myroute">
    <from uri="timer://runOnce?repeatCount=1&amp;delay=10" />

    <to uri="bean:myPOJOFactory?method=newMyPOJO" />

    <!-- Not sure what to do here -->
    <!-- MyPOJO#Fizz should get routed to direct:fizzFarm. -->
    <!-- MyPOJO#Buzz should get routed to direct:buzzFarm. -->
</route>
```

Where `myPOJOFactory` is:

```
public class MyPOJOFactory {
    public MyPOJO newMyPOJO(Exchange exchange) {
        Fizz fizz = new Fizz(true, 3);
        Buzz buzz = new Buzz("awesome");

        MyPOJO pojo = new MyPOJO(fizz, buzz);

        exchange.getOut().setBody(pojo);
    }
}
```

I need a way to now split the `MyPOJO` instance (created inside the `myPOJOFactory` bean) into its constituent `Fizz` and `Buzz` properties, and route the `Fizz` one way, and the `Buzz` another way.

My understanding of a [Splitter](http://camel.apache.org/splitter.html) is that it just takes the body of the exchange and breaks it up into a collection of 2+ objects. But I don't think this is what I want, because although I do want the `MyPOJO` to get "split" into its constituent `Fizz` and `Buzz` fields, I want them routed to different destinations. Perhaps `Fizz` goes to `direct:fizzFarm` and `Buzz` goes to `direct:buzzFarm`.

My understanding of a [Content-Based Router](http://camel.apache.org/content-based-router.html) (`<choice/>`) is that it allows you to add condition `if-else-if` logic into a route. But I don't think I want this either because what I need isn't conditional: I **always** want the `MyPOJO#Fizz` to go to `direct:fizzFarm`, and I **always** want the `MyPOJO#Buzz` to go to `direct:buzzFarm`.

My understanding of a [Dynamic Router](http://camel.apache.org/dynamic-router.html) is that it will dynamically route messages to different destinations, although I'm not quite sure how yet. I *believe* this is what I want, however, coming out of the `myPOJOFactory` bean, the exchange will contain a `MyPOJO` object. I feel like I have to first split the `MyPOJO` prior to sending it into a dynamic router. That way, the dynamic router will be able to clearly see whether the message is a `Fizz` or a `Buzz`, and route it correctly.

So I believe I need to use a splitter in conjunction with a dynamic router. I'm just not seeing the forest through the trees. Something like this:

```
<route id="myroute">
    <from uri="timer://runOnce?repeatCount=1&amp;delay=10" />

    <to uri="bean:myPOJOFactory?method=newMyPOJO" />

    <split>
        <tokenize token="Somehow split MyPOJO into Fizz and Buzz here" />
        <to uri="direct:dynrouter" />
    </split>

    <from uri="direct:dynrouter" />

    <dynamicRouter>
        <!-- ??? Somehow route Fizz to direct:fizzFarm, and Buzz to direct:buzzFarm
    </dynamicRouter>
</route>
```

Any ideas as to how I can accomplish this (#1 splitting `MyPOJO` into `Fizz` and `Buzz`, and #2 setting up a router to route `Fizz` and `Buzz` to different destinations)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're right, since the logic is always the same, the routers might be overkill.

Splitters are most often used with objects of the same type (e.g. splitting a list and processing each item separately)

So can I suggest the [Multicast EIP](http://camel.apache.org/multicast.html), something like this should work:

```
from("timer://runOnce?repeatCount=1&delay=10")
    .bean(myPOJOFactory.class)
    .multicast().to("direct:sendFizz", "direct:sendBuzz")

from("direct:sendFizz")
    .setBody(simple("${body.fizz"))
    .to("direct:fizzFarm")

from("direct:sendBuzz")
    .setBody(simple("${body.buzz"))
    .to("direct:buzzFarm")
```

(This is obviously DSL syntax, you can also try it in XML).

Comment: Awesome answer, great advise! This was easy to convert to Spring XML, thanks again!